# Zend Framework: Dao model

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, dao, zend-db, zend-db-table

I have been given a problem statement and i am relatively new to zend framework.

/

```
> **
>      * create a new lead
>      *
>      * planId will be sent $_GET['planId'], the form should send the action to
>      * the same page
>      * a user should be logged in and he should be administrator of the plan
>      * 
>      * @uses Plans_Model_Dao_Moderator::isAdmin
>      * @throws unauthorized exception, catch the exception in error controller
>      
> 
> > *         get the form from form builder module
> >      * @uses Formbuilder_Model_Dao_Form::getForm
> >      *       save in database
> >      * @uses Leads_Model_Dao_Lead::save
> >      *       send notifications to _POST['to']
> >      * @uses Zend_Mail
```

from the earlier question posted on this forum i could understand ,how to check the administrative rights i could understand it better ..but then i am still stuck with latter part i.e

```
@uses Formbuilder_Model_Dao_Form::getForm
> >      *       save in database
> >      * @uses Leads_Model_Dao_Lead::save
> >      *       send notifications to _POST['to']
> >      * @uses Zend_Mail
```

any help with how to proceed with it will really be helpful..

Answer (score 0):

In the 2nd part, it is suggesting:
- get the form in the controller & send to the view
- on successful submission of the form save to the database
- on successful save send an notification email using the email address from the POST with the key 'to'